# Apply media query style to media print?

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

I have a CSS document with partly "normal" css and some changes that are made to the css when the window is being resized:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 767px) {

/* css */

}
```

Now when I print my HTML page, it just uses the "normal" css.

However, when printing the page I would like to use the "normal" CSS PLUS the part from this media query.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: add media="print" in css inclusion tag

Comment: Do you mean I have to write `@media screen, print` instead?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html

Comment: So I just copy my media query CSS to a new `@media print`?

Comment: @2339870 yes, copy/paste, done :)

Comment: Ankur's solution is wrong, I don't know why two people upvoted it. If you add media="print" to the link element, then only print media would apply that stylesheet. But then you have an `@media only screen and ...` rule inside it. That means the styles inside that rule will **never** be used because screen media won't see print stylesheets and print media won't see screen styles.

Comment: @Morpheus: You don't have to copy and paste anything - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a comma followed by `print` to your `@media` rule like so:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 767px), print {

/* css */

}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

html

```
 <header>
     <h1>header</h1>
 </header>
<section>
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="item"> ITEM1 </div>
    <div class="item"> ITEM1 </div>
    <div class="item"> ITEM1 </div>
    <div class="item"> ITEM1 </div>
    <div class="item"> ITEM1 </div>
    <div class="item"> ITEM1 </div>
    <div class="item"> ITEM1 </div>
    <div class="item"> ITEM1 </div>
 </div>
</section>
 <footer>
   <h1>footer</h1>
</footer>
```

//css

```
@media screen and (max-width:420px){
  .item{
    color:red;
  }
}
@media  screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width:960px){
   .item{
    color:green;
   }
}
 @media screen and (min-width: 720px) and (max-width:1024px){
    .item{
     color:blue;
   }
 }
@media screen and (min-width:1024px){
  .item{
     color:orchid;
   }
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/qV55M/1/)

Comment: What does this have to do with anything besides the word "print"?